# Selecting image labels from list using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have created an image of forest patches, where each patch is assigned a unique label. Then, using various points from a table, I created buffers to select the complete patches surrounding each point. I can generate a list with the labels of the patches that intersect the buffers, but I encounter difficulties when attempting to mask the original image of connected patches to retain only the patches in the list. How can I do this?

Here is an example:

```
var cc75 = ee.Number(75); var canopyCover = forestcover.select(['treecover2000']); var canopyCover75 = canopyCover.gte(cc75).selfMask();

var connectedPatches = canopyCover75.connectedComponents({ connectedness: ee.Kernel.plus(1), maxSize: 128 });

// Crete a Buffer 
var bufferDistance = 500; //
var puntosBuffer = puntos.map(function(feature) { return feature.buffer(bufferDistance); });

var sampledLabels = connectedPatches.select('labels').reduceRegions({ collection: puntosBuffer, reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), scale: 30, });

// Extract labels of sampled features 
var labelsList = sampledLabels.aggregate_array('list');

// Flatten list 
var flatList = labelsList.flatten().distinct();

var imageLabels= connectedPatches.select('labels')

// Trying to select just one label 
var prueba = connectedPatches.select('labels').eq(6896948677769589)

var remapped = prueba.remap({ from: flatList, to: ee.List.repeat(0, flatList.size()), defaultValue: 0 })
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on one task, and what your code is doing that falls short of need.